# Setting a Custom error message in an Compare Attribute in .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to compare two password fields with a Compare Attribute and in my project, I use an HTML helper to get the message in different languages depending on the language id and I can not use my method in the error message

```
[LocalizedRequired("PasswordRequired")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
        [LocalizedRequired("PasswordDoesntMatch")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password doesn't match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassowrd { get; set; }
```

This is the model without the helper and it works fine, the problem is that if I use any method that returns a string error message it doesn't work at all.

```
[LocalizedRequired("PasswordRequired")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
        [LocalizedRequired("PasswordDoesntMatch")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage = Kuvendi.Infrastructure.MVC.HtmlHelperExtensions.DrawLabel("Password doesn't match")))]
        public string ConfirmPassowrd { get; set; }
```

Draw label is an HTML helper method that returns strings for a specific language id, the helper returns strings successfully and it is tested.

**I appreciate your time.**

Comment: "doesn't work at all": please *in the question* show your non-working code *and* explain in what way it varies from your expectation.

Comment: ok i will edit it right now

Answer (score 0):

Parameters passed to attributes must be compile time constants, so you can not call any helper methods to generate them.

You can however provide the name of a string resource and the resource file. Language [will be resolved](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160340/Get-insight-to-build-your-first-Multi-Language-ASP) by MVC and the translation from the correct resource file will be selected.

```
[LocalizedRequired("PasswordDoesntMatch")]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordDoesntMatch")]
public string ConfirmPassowrd { get; set; }
```

Comment: The resource type 'MySql.Data.Resources' does not have an accessible static property named 'PasswordDoesntMatch'.                                                             
                                                                 
                                                            
                System.InvalidOperationException: The resource type 'MySql.Data.Resources' does not have an accessible static property named 'PasswordDoesntMatch'.

Comment: this is the error message that this code returns to me

Comment: Yes, the `Resources.resx` file must exist and contain a string resource with key `PasswordDoesntMatch`. Also make sure that your MVC project is set up to pass the correct language (see link in my post).

Comment: does it mean that i can use a different label and it will work??

Comment: Yes, just provide the key for the resource and which .resx file to use...

Comment: the language is passed successfully in the application for sure, and i will read the post you provided me with

Comment: Then it should look for translations in `Resources.en.resx`, `Resources.fr.resx` and so on depending on the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. Fallback will be `Resources.resx`.

Comment: By default the resource files are in the Project/Properties.